# que significa passing argument 3 of ‘intento’ from incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de que el código funcione usando punteros pero saltan las alertas ("message": "passing argument 3 of 'intento' makes pointer from integer without a cast), tenia pensado pasar arreglo como  para cambiarlo dentro de la función.

Lo que hace el programa es pedirle al usuario el tamaño del arreglo, pide numeros que se almaceneran en el mismo y luego mediante funciones pedirá que se busque un numero de entre los que que ingreso el usuario y nos dira si esta o no. Por favor ayudaaa

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"


int intento(int indice,int tama,int *arreglo[indice]){


    //impresion de los valores ingresados
printf ("\nLos valores ingresados fueron:");
    for(indice=0; indice<tama; indice++){

        printf("[%d]",arreglo[indice]);
    }

return 0;
}

int buscador(int indice,int tama,int *arreglo[indice],int num){
    
    //funcion encargada de buscar el numero
 
 printf ("\nIngrese el numero que desea buscar de entre los numeros anteriormente ingresados: ");
 scanf("%d", &num);
 
 for (indice=0; indice<tama; indice++){
    if(num==arreglo[indice]){
       printf("El numero se encuentra en el arreglo!!!!", num);
      
   }//if
}//for

if (num==0){
    printf("**El numero no se encuentra**");
}

 return 0;
}

int main() {
int tama=0, indice=0;
int num;


    printf("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo: ");
    scanf ("%d", &tama);

    //declaracion del arreglo

    int arreglo[tama];
    for(indice=0; indice<=tama-1; indice++){
        printf ("Ingrese los valores: ");
        scanf ("%d", &arreglo[indice]);
    }

    //impresion de los valores ingresados
intento(indice,tama, arreglo);

   //buscador del numero
   buscador(indice,tama, arreglo, num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pasar un int array como argumento de una función simplemente debes pasar un puntero a este array de la forma `int *nombre_del_array`, en tu caso debería ser `int *arreglo`. Sin quererlo, tu estás definiendo el parámetro de entrada arreglo de las funciones intento y buscador como un puntero a un array multidimensional y no es el caso.
Al usar las funciones tu pasas un int* pero estas esperan un int** y por eso te lanza un incompatibilidad de tipos.
Por otro lado, yo pondría `printf("El numero se encuentra en el arreglo!!!!", num)` como `printf("El numero %d se encuentra en el arreglo!!!!", num)`. En resumen, sin darle muchas más vueltas tu código quedaría así:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"


int intento(int indice,int tama,int *arreglo){


    //impresion de los valores ingresados
printf ("\nLos valores ingresados fueron:");
    for(indice=0; indice<tama; indice++){

        printf("[%d]",arreglo[indice]);
    }

return 0;
}

int buscador(int indice,int tama,int *arreglo,int num){
    
    //funcion encargada de buscar el numero
 
 printf ("\nIngrese el numero que desea buscar de entre los numeros anteriormente ingresados: ");
 scanf("%d", &num);
 
 for (indice=0; indice<tama; indice++){
    if(num==arreglo[indice]){
       printf("El numero %d se encuentra en el arreglo!!!!", num);
      
   }//if
}//for

if (num==0){
    printf("**El numero no se encuentra**");
}

 return 0;
}

int main() {
int tama=0, indice=0;
int num;


    printf("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo: ");
    scanf ("%d", &tama);

    //declaracion del arreglo

    int arreglo[tama];
    for(indice=0; indice<=tama-1; indice++){
        printf ("Ingrese los valores: ");
        scanf ("%d", &arreglo[indice]);
    }

    //impresion de los valores ingresados
intento(indice,tama, arreglo);

   //buscador del numero
   buscador(indice,tama, arreglo, num);
    return 0;
}
```